# How do I force user to run command with sudo privilege

Tags: sudo

I want to write a python script, hope that user can run it only if he has sudo privilege.

So, my question is how to check if user has sudo privilege and if user run script with sudo.

my os is centos 5.7 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
class NotSudo(Exception):
    pass
if os.getuid() != 0:
    raise NotSudo("This program is not run as sudo or elevated this it will not work")
```